# I want to print the output from DOMXPath in 2 colomns. 1. Car name 2. Price

Tags: php

I have tried the following code:

```
  $car_row = $car_xpath->query('//h3[@class="adtitlesnb"]');
  $car_row2 = $car_xpath->query('//div[@class="snb_price_tag"]');


  $i = 0;    

  echo "<table><thead><tr><td>Car Name</td><td>Price</td></tr></thead><tbody>";

  foreach($car_row as $row){

     echo "<tr><td>";
     echo $row->nodeValue;
     echo "</td><td>";
     echo $car_row2->nodeValue;
     echo "</td></tr>";

  }

  echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Comment: plz somebody correct the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't iterate over one array with foreach and expect the other to follow.

`foreach` essentially resets the current index on an array, then loops through calling next on the array until there are no elements left. Using `reset` and `next` you can emulate this for your second array as follows:

```
    $car_row = $car_xpath->query('//h3[@class="adtitlesnb"]');
    $car_row2 = $car_xpath->query('//div[@class="snb_price_tag"]');

    echo "<table><thead><tr><td>Car Name</td><td>Price</td></tr></thead><tbody>";

    $row2 = reset($car_row2);  // set the internal array pointer to the begining
    foreach($car_row as $row) {
       echo "<tr><td>";
       echo $row->nodeValue;
       echo "</td><td>";
       echo $row2->nodeValue;
       echo "</td></tr>";
       $row2 = next($car_row2); // retrieve the next node from car_row2
    }

  echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Comment: Thanku.. But m getting this error:  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Nehan\test.php on line 37

Comment: this is my 37th line.

Comment: What are you using to generate your Xpath query? Is it DOMXPath? if so you can't iterate with foreach, and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong, that should work with DOMXPath. Was your original code working and my code broke it? I can't see what your 37th line is to try and work it out. Are $car_row and $car_row2 definitly the same length?

Comment: my 37th line:  echo $row2->nodeValue;

Comment: it was printing only the car names. and it is doing the same with your code. and yes both $car_row and $car_row2 are of same length.

Comment: I've just made a modification to my code which will hopefully work;

Comment: Same error, with the same line. No changes in the output as well.

Comment: hey DorianFM. help me out.

Comment: can you add `echo $car_row->length.' '.$car_row2->length.'<br>'` before the loop and tell me the output?